# Sanity check on d3.line generator not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am creating a path using a d3.line() generator for my data. The path is not showing up at all and I am left wondering what is missing. When inspecting the elements, you see the path element is created but it is empty (see below).
[image]

I added a console.log(0 to my line generator to see if would show up, however, it does not. My code is below:

```
    let innerBars = attributeNodes.append('g');

    let lineGen = d3.line()
    .x(d=> {
        console.log(d.move) //this does not show up in console
        return d.move})
    .y(d=> d.attributes.beakD.scaledVal);

    innerBars.append('path')
    .attr("d", d=> {
        console.log(d) //This console.logs the right data
        return lineGen(d)})
    .attr("class", "inner-line");
```

The right data is being passed down to the path element, but the line generator is not working to generate the path.
Any tips on what might be going on here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You note the console logs the right data, before calling the line generator, what does it look like at this step?

Comment: I was attempting to create a line from separate nodes in an array instead of the entire array. I adjusted the way I was binding the data and it works now. Thank you for the reply @AndrewReid!